# 404 after Woocommerce plugin activation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404

I have an error 404 after WooCommerce plugin activation.
I use the next plugins: WooCommerce, WooCommerce Multilingual and all WPML CMS.
But after deactivation all pages and posts are working.
I use Cyrillic CHPU may It be a cause?

Can anyone help? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing permalink structure, then change it back immediately.

Comment: Thank you! 
I tried It early and now but It is not help. I think It depends of some options in WPML...

Comment: Try to inactive plugins one by one so can get exact ides which noe causing problem, also check your .htaccess file

Comment: Thank you for advice. Few minutes ago I lose this problem although  the reasons are not clear. I deactivated all plugins and try to activate It one by one. After few activation orders I got successfully working site. So I must make an conclusion: you must activate at first the most 
heaviest plugins like WooCommerce, WPML and The Events Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lose this problem although the reasons are not clear. I deactivated all plugins and try to activate It one by one. After few activation orders I got successfully working site. So I must make an conclusion: you must activate at first the most heaviest plugins like WooCommerce, WPML and The Events Calendar.